# Http connection on black berry v 4.6

Tags: blackberry

How can I create HttpConnection for v4.6,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the API docs on [HttpConnection](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/javax/microedition/io/HttpConnection.html). There are sample code in there.

Comment: // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  //Dialog.alert("Hello how are you");
HttpConnection c=null;
InputStream is=null;
int rc;
try{
 c=(HttpConnection)Connector.open("http://google.com");
   rc = c.getResponseCode();
      if (rc != HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
          throw new IOException("HTTP response code: " + rc);
      }
      else
       Dialog.alert("Hello");
      
 
}// end of the try
catch(Exception e){
 Dialog.alert(e+"");
 
 
}

Comment: above code is giving  ConnectionInterruptedException  ,time out for 1200 s .though i am using http://localhost,,, same error occurs

Comment: Have you heard about network transports? If not - check this: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Connecting-your-BlackBerry-http-and-socket-connections-to-the/m-p/206243